# Yodlee Fastlink Login Takes too Long

Tags: yodlee

I've been building a prototype for account information gathering using the `Yodlee` API, and was playing around with their pre-made UI at first.

All of the features for the Fastlink UI worked, however the load times for after log-in processing were unacceptably slow...sometimes taking up to 30-45 seconds for verification and information display.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. The bulk of the delay times comes from the delay for the registry of MFA services.

The `providers/providerAccounts/{id}` endpoint is continuously called until the MFA data is available which in some cases takes some time.